# Is PHP 5.3.x less secure than PHP 5.6.x

Tags: php, security, php-5.3, php-5.6

Does the version of PHP effect the security of my website?

[This article](https://updraftplus.com/php-version-matter/), among others, points to a mild & vague 'yes.'

Comment: One would hope so. There are a lot of security fixes between two versions. And there are new APIs that are supported in later versions than older. But the biggest reason to change to 5.6 (or rather jump right to 7.x) is that the language has improved, significantly.

Comment: Almost every PHP update has included some sort of security related improvement.  See: PHP 5 ChangeLog http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php
PHP 7 ChangeLog http://php.net/ChangeLog-7.php

Comment: ...not to mention speed. PHP gets way faster between versions (7 is several times faster than 5.3) and more memory efficient...

Comment: It depends on where you got your PHP 5.3 version, and if you're using one maintained by an OS vendor as mentioned in that article, whether or not you're keeping it updated. (Of course that last part applies to any version.)

Comment: beside, php5.3 doesn't have Security Support from _years_: http://php.net/supported-versions.php so no release to fix critical security issue.

Comment: @Jite et. al.  Thank you for the answers. This is the insight I was looking for. Most excellent.

Answer (score 1):

The mild & vague answer comes from a mild & vague question. You need to create a question that expects an answer that is not limited to "yes" or "no".

Your question "Does the version of PHP effect the security of my website?" can only accept two answers: "yes" or "no".

So, **Yes**, it affects the security. (may be positive, or negative, but affects)

If you ask, instead: "What are the security differences between two PHP versions?" then this question will not accept "yes" or "no", and will need an more detailed explanation, that, I think, its what you're looking for.

Comment: Is binary not the most fundamental, and therefore most elegant question type? Perhaps I should create a new thread. ;)
Thank you for the feedback.